# Is E3 license consider Low or Medium or High Performance profile

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, powerapp

I am reading this article about Performance Profiles and their relation with licensing, but the info are a bit confusing @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config#looping-and-debatching-limits . now based on the official documentation >> E3 is consider Low Performance profile. but in our case i have a service account with E3 license >> and this user can define an GetItems SharePoint action with paging = 100,000:-

[image]

and this feature (define a pagination of 100,000) should not be part of the low profile users, where low profile users should only define max of 5000 for the paginating inside GetItem.. so can anyone advice on this licensing case/confusion?

Here is the list of trial and paid licenses the user have :-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user has multiple plans, such as a Microsoft 365 plan and a Dynamics 365 plan, the flow will have the performance profile of the higher of the two plans.

Comment: i thought trail licenses will not be counted